# Remove specific filters for a specific visual

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have a PowerBI Report embedded. I want to remove specific visual level filters for a visual. But with Remove visual filters it removes all the filters applied to that visual.

How Can I achieve remove only specific visual level filters.

Answer (score 1):

We don't have a filter operation to remove specific filters for a visual. But You can use Replace operation and pass the new filter array.

`await report.updateFilters(models.FiltersOperations.Replace, [filter]);`

References:
https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/control-report-filters